# It's possible to design a program that works like cells in a human body (or life)?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

I always think that life in general is really very complex and we don't even know all about it. But it works, right? that lead me to think if it was possible to think of a program as thinking of a group of differentiated cells. or maybe totipotent (the ones that can differentiate in any other cell) cells that differentiated.

I don't know if this is the right place to ask because involves biology and reprogramming.
 thanks for interest

Comment: Computer viruses and worms could be said to mimic some aspects of life.

Comment: Is there an actual question here, apart from the rhetorical one about whether life works? If not, this might be a conversation best held in the pub.

Comment: the question is in the title... And life certainly works, that's not the question.

Comment: That's incredibly vague though - do you mean the way life reproduces, stores information, builds cells, differentiates cells, selectively edits RNA, heals, adapts to stimuli, forms functional multi-cellular structures, what?

Comment: I think your question is too vague to answer. Be more specific

Answer (score 3):

If your question is as stated in the title the you ought to look into Artificial Life and Digital Life. The prime example of Digital Life is [Avida](http://avida.devosoft.org/), where you have a bunch of computer programs thought of as organisms who compete for computer resources (such as CPU time and memory). Another example is the research by Schlessinger et. al. ([paper here](http://lottolab.websites.bta.com/pdf/publications/65_1.pdf)). They created digital single-celled organisms that could aggregate into a multi-cellular organism. Furthermore, the cells in their research are differentiated in that not all of them can perform all actions.

Moreover, there is a fair amount of research on computer simulations of morphogenesis, embryogenesis, cell differentiation, cell division etc.

Answer (score 2):

The established field of Genetic Algorithms might be worth exploring:
http://www.catonmat.net/blog/genetic-algorithms-101/

http://delicious.com/tag/geneticalgorithm

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague. But you should consider to look in the field of Systems Biology. If you are interested I provide you an article by H. Kitano [Systems biology: A brief overview](http://theory.bio.uu.nl/BPA/pdf/Obligatory_reading/Kitano_s02.pdf)

During my internship I have been simulating/modeling a very simple cell of a microorganisms to study its behavior. But from my understanding to simulate a cell of human body is extremely difficult to do not to speak of modeling an eukarotic cell...

Answer (score 0):

Programs basically already work this way.

The linux [fork()](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl2_fork.htm) command - duplicate the current [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), and starts running it from the the same point in both processes. The program "knows" if this program is the original or the forked one, and invokes a code with respect to it [if the programmer designed it to do it, of course]

Also note, that like cells - all linux processes have the same origin - there is one process which is responsible for creating all others.

Comment: I mean in terms of organization. How they organize the information. couldn't we organize the same/similar way too?

Comment: @Totty: I don't understand what you are asking, you specifically asked about "totipotent programs" [which the init process in linux kinda mimic] and "differentiated programs" [which are running for specific purpose processes]. Could you clarify what you mean by "terms of organization"?

Comment: how the totipotent cells organize it's data. I mean: how they know that at age of 10 that teeth have to fall and another should be grow. How they know that the totipotent cell have to differentiate in how quantity and in which kind of cell?

Comment: @Totty: some are event triggered [example: the user invokes a new program] others are time base triggered [example: when the OS reschaduels processes - because time for this process was exhausted] and some are control-flow based [example: The program finished a while loop since the condition is no longer met, and is going to the next stage]

Comment: but I would like to know more in a large picture, more like software-architecture level